# Can't switch between pip for python 3.4 and 2.7 [Windows]

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have python 3.4 installed on my windows for a while but now I need to get 2.7 to work another project. I downloaded the 2.7.10 package from the official python and installed it. Everything was fine until I tried to install packages using pip.

What I have read in different places is that pip-2.7 should work but the command is not recognized. If I get get-pip.py to try to install pip using py get-pip.py it tells me it's already installed.

So is there anyway to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel)

> py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
>
> py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
>
> py -3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
>
> py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4

So in your case you'll need either of the two:

```
py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
```